# C: How to replace GtkAlignment function with newer GtkWidget align property

Tags: c, function, gtk, gtk3

I am a new C programmer coming from Java. After reading some old books and articles, I've written the following code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void activate(GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data) {
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *button1;
    GtkWidget *box;

    box = gtk_alignment_new(0, 0, 0, 0);

    window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Calculator");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 400);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), box);

    button1 = gtk_button_new();
    gtk_button_set_label(GTK_BUTTON(button1), "1");
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(button1, 40, 30);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(box), button1);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    app = gtk_application_new("me.test.calculator", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);

    return status;
}
```

The code compiles and runs correctly. The problem is that *gtk_alignment_new* is deprecated and I want to get rid of it.

I've tried replacing *gtk_alignment_new* with:

```
gtk_widget_set_halign(box, GTK_ALIGN_START);
gtk_widget_set_valign(box, GTK_ALIGN_START);
```

but the window does not show up when using this method. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set the halign/valign properties of the *button* (and then add the button straight into the window) to achieve the same functional results as your original code. 'box' is no longer needed at all.

Note that a GtkWindow is a GtkBin so only takes a single child: you will need to add additional containers in between to actually make a calculator. Maybe start by adding a GtkGrid as the sole window child and then attach all your buttons into the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Using jku's advice I've written the following code which compiles and runs correctly without using *gtk_alignment_new*:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void activate(GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data) {
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *button1;
    GtkWidget *fixed;

    fixed = gtk_fixed_new();

    window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Calculator");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 400);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), fixed);

    button1 = gtk_button_new();
    gtk_button_set_label(GTK_BUTTON(button1), "1");
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(button1, 45, 35);
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), button1, 5, 200);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    app = gtk_application_new("me.test.calculator", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);

    return status;
}
```

**NOTE**: I ended up using GtxFixed because the size of the window will be fixed as well.

Comment: Please, never use GtkFixed for such reason. Chances are your application will have to be maintained in the future, and doing fixed sized stuff is almost always a bad idea.